# How to get iPad/iPhone Cellular Network Data >Sent/Received Usage so my app doesn't kill users Data Plan

Tags: iphone, ipad, settings

The iPad is coming to the Uk and so are the expensive data plans.
My app downloads large pdf files.
I prompt the user if they are on 3g if they wish to continue but it there any way to access the IPhone setting for data downloaded so I could do a before/after.
Im looking for
IPhone > Settings > General > Usage > Cellular Network Data > Sent/Received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to access this information from inside your application. You could just measure the size of the file(s) you download, and display that.

Comment: yes after further thought im going to try the following: 
i'll cache the downloaded files. if user on 3G prompt them do they want to down load the files. Scan all the files myself and store their sizes. cheers

Answer (score 0):

On 3.x, these are got using the private functions `CTRegistrationDataCounterGet***Statistics` in Core Telephony framework.

(And even Core Telephony becomes public in 4.0, this is still a private function.)