# How can I measure my app's data traffic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm developing an iPad app, which loads some images and does video calls. The images are retrieved over http, and the video stream is over rtp. Is there a way to measure all download and upload that is being performed by my app?
I'm not looking for a debug tool, I'd like to log how much bandwidth customers use.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7946699/2106973

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get iPad/iPhone Cellular Network Data >Sent/Received Usage so my app doesn't kill users Data Plan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818763/how-to-get-ipad-iphone-cellular-network-data-sent-received-usage-so-my-app-does)

Comment: @monolo I don't think it's a duplicate, because that post is very old and the answer might have changed since then with a newer sdk.

Comment: @Kevin you may be right, although my understanding is that per-app data counters have not been implemented since then.

Comment: As you said, the images are retrieved over http... so they must be in a server in internet.. and every server has a page that gives you statistics on bandwidth, visualizations, etc,... if you don't know where to find that just ask to your provider... If you have access at c-panel you should find everything there.

Comment: @blue If it were just the images, I'd just measure them client side. If I check how big each image's data is, I can make a close enough calculation on bandwidth use. The real problem lies with the video calls, RTP is a peer to peer protocol, so there is no server involved.

Comment: Every time you make a video call you could add a unit to a int and then save it in a server with some php code and some objective-c code to read and write the file in your server...
if this could solve your problem I can put some code I usually use to do things like this...

Comment: "and every server has a page that gives you statistics on bandwidth, visualizations, etc" - No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Google Analytics SDK